# How to effectively render video in Java (AWT??)

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, awt, java-2d

In my project I've got a class `FrameProducer` firing events each time a video frame has been created. Each frame is an image returned as an `java.awt.Image.BufferedImage` object.

I've got 2 `FrameProducer` objects and would like to render `BufferedImage's` produced by them simultaneously on the screen. I would like the picture rendered on the screen to be **scalable** (that is, when I drag the application-window's corner the rendered video gets smaller or bigger).

How do you think this is best to be achieved?

I've considered using `java.awt.Graphics2D` embedded in an `java.awt.Frame`, but I don't know how such a thing can be done, or if this is the best choice. I just need this for algorithm visualisation, it doesn't need to be nice and shiny, just fast and easy. What would some suggestions or some ready code be that I could use?

---

**Edit:**
OK, I implemented the solution as Rekin suggested, and it works. But as I'm not an Java expert and definitely not a [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) expert, I'd like to ask you for kind remarks on my code - I'm sure many will benefit from that in the future.

As I said, there is a `FrameProducer` (never mind the implementation):

```
public abstract class FrameProducer extends Observable {
    public abstract BufferedImage getFrame();

    public void fireEvent() {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Then there is also a `FrameRenderer` waiting for events from the `FrameProducer` (a simple observer-pattern implementation using `java.util`):

```
public class FrameRenderer extends JPanel implements Observer {
    private BufferedImage frame;
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(frame, null, 0, 0);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Cought an event from " + observable.getClass());
        if (observable instanceof FrameProducer) {
            frame = ((FrameProducer) observable).getFrame();
            paint(getGraphics());
        }
    }
}
```

And then there is also the thing that needs rework: the `MainFrame`.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    FrameProducer[] producers;

    public MainFrame(FrameProducer[] producers) {
        this.setTitle("Playing what you feed.");
        this.producers = producers;
        initContents();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initContents() {
        FrameRenderer renderer = new FrameRenderer();
        renderer.setLocation(0, 0);
        this.add(renderer);
        producers[0].addObserver(renderer);
    }
}
```

It all gets initialised in the main method:

```
public class FrameAccessTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final FrameProducer frameGrabber = new CameraFrameGrabber("vfw://0");

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame mainFrame =
                        new MainFrame(new FrameProducer[] {frameGrabber});
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**How do I implement initContents() in such a way, that all the video streams provided in `MainFrame's` constructor as `FrameProducer[]` get rendered in a row and that they are scalable?**

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with JPanel and overriding `paintComponent` method. In it I'd use `Graphics2D.drawImage()` giving width and height of container as a parameters to it.

The AWT approach seems closer to bare metal, but since JDK 6 brought a lot of improvements in Swing rendering pipeline, I would go the Swing & Java2D approach. It's accelerated by available hardware (using DirectDraw on Windows or OpenGL wherever possible) and hides a lot of low level details behind a nice API. For example You get double buffering for free.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll give it a shot and post my code when done, maybe you'll have any comments.

Comment: Glad to be of any help. I faced similar challenge a number of times. Also got a little OpenGL expertise out of it, so don't hesitate asking.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `paintComponent` method and use Graphics2D to draw your buffered image using `drawImage`. This method is overloaded and can be used to scale the image as well.